# Property [business_url] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

My business can have many pages and here i am defining my model:

```
class PageList extends Model
{
    public function business()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Business','business_id');
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
public function pageListHere()
{
    $list = PageList::all();
    return view('page-list',compact('list'));
}
```

and my view having for each loop

```
<td>{{optional($value->business)->business_url}}.spikesales.io/{{$value->page_url}}</td>
```

In my relation ship if i do `hasOne('App\Business','business_id');` it works fine but its only display one page against business but i have multiple pages in my database and one business can have many pages and if write `hasMany('App\Business','business_id');` it show me the error  Property [business_url] does not exist on this collection instance

I want to show the multiple pages against one business.
your help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are a little bit confused. In your model, you are actually defining the relation `A page has many businesses`, and you are telling that the `businesses` table has a column `business_id`, which Laravel tried to find but couldn't, resulting in an error.

---

The `hasMany` function works in this way:

```
// In the Post Model...
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'post_number');
}
```

This makes the relation **`A Post has many Comments`** and makes Laravel assume that the **`comments` table has `post_number` column**.

---

You want to show multiple pages against one business. So, **`A business has many Pages`.** To code it...

```
// In your BUSINESS model...
public function pages() {
    // Notice that $this refers to the Business Model
    return $this->hasMany('App\PageList', 'business_id');
}
```

You can optionally (but I think you should) omit the `'business_id'` part.  It will safely be assumed by default.

And the inverse of the relation, **`A Page belongs to A business`**, will be coded as...

```
// In your PAGELIST model...
public function business() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Business');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop/iterate over the business relationship since the result will return in a array of collection:

```
@foreach($lists as $list)
   // others markup
   @foreach($list->business as $business)
      // do something here
      {{ $business->business_url }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```